# SQLite Adding Previous Week Column to Current Week

Tags: sqlite

I have the following data

```
   Week    Country       Quantity     Price 
    1       Sweden          2          $10
    1       Germany         3          $20
    2       Sweden          10         $20
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
 Country Quantity Price  Current Week Revenue  Past Week Revenue 
 Sweden   30      100         300        3000    2000
```

If I was just doing Country, Quantity, Price, Current Week I'd use

```
SELECT Country, sum(uantity), sum(price), sum(price*quantity) as         
    revenue
    from dataset where Week = 1 Group by Country.
```

However, I am at loss on how to add the previous week given that the where statement restricts the data to one week only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation.  That is, move the condition from the `where` to the `sum()` aggregation functions:

```
SELECT Country,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Week = 1 THEN quantity END) as quantity_1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Week = 1 THEN price END) as price_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Week = 1 THEN price*quantity END) as revenue_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Week = 2 THEN quantity END) as quantity_2, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Week = 2 THEN price END) as price_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Week = 2 THEN price*quantity END) as revenue_2
FROM dataset d
WHERE Week IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY Country;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, use a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) to loop up the previous week's data:

```
SELECT Country,
       SUM(Quantity * Price) AS Revenue,
       (SELECT SUM(Quantity * Price)
        FROM dataset AS PrevWeek
        WHERE PrevWeek.Week = dataset.Week - 1
          AND PrevWeek.Country = dataset.Country
       ) AS "Past Week Revenue"
FROM dataset
GROUP BY Country;
```